# Compile NSIS under Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nsis

I download nsis-2.46-src.tar.bz2 from https://sourceforge.net/projects/nsis/files/ and I'm trying to compile makensis but get the errors like:

```
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `build/release/makensis/winchar.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
build.cpp:(.text+0x35eb): undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::append(char const*, unsigned int)'
```

What is wrong? And where I can get Stubs, Plugins, Include components after compilation of makensis? Help me please.

Before compilation I have install mingw-w64, gcc, g++

Comment: Any reason why [this one](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/nsis) is bad?

Comment: There are some patches in the debian package for nsis which mention something about architecture.